# How to Check/Display Last Password Change Time for User in Wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I'm still learning the ropes on using mysql/wordpress but I stumbled on a curious problem.

Is there a way to check the last time a user updated their password?

Can this be done via Wordpress (plugins) or Phpmyadmin?

I tried several solutions including querying the database via Phpmyadmin for last update time

i.e using - show table status from your_database like 'your_table';

but it doesn't show the last update time for the specific user row in the wp_users table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like WordPress does not store any value regarding the last time when user changes his password. So what you can do is to explicitly save a new user meta field with a value of current timestamp whenever any user changes his password and update it accordingly when he change it later on again.

Answer (score 1):

You could do that by modifying wp_users table by adding a new column, let's say mod_time. Then you will need to modify wp-login.php.

```
/**
 * Fires before the lost password form.
 *
 * @since 1.5.1
 */
$modification_time = date("F j, Y, g:i a");
do_action( 'lost_password' );

login_header(__('Lost Password'), '<p class="message">' . __('Please enter your username or email address. You will receive a link to create a new password via email.') . '</p>', $errors);

$user_login = isset($_POST['user_login']) ? wp_unslash($_POST['user_login']) : '';
$wpdb->insert( wp_users, array( 'mod_time' => $modification_time ), %s );
```

The next thing is to modify your admin backend to retrieve the mod_time column and show it as you wish.
If I am not busy I will write a plugin for that in the next days. The code above is not tested. Hope this helps.